# Getting corresponding auto-generated ID's in SQL to match XML passed values

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql

I am new to SQL, and XML so please bear with me. I have a query that gets values entered into a multi-line textbox, passes them as xml to @data xml parameter declared and then writes them to the History and Diary tables respectively.  Along with other parameters declared.

So, my problem is, it is first written to the Diary table where the ID's in that table is auto-generated, say 551 and 552 respectively for the below matters, THEN the information is inserted to the History table.  This should not happen.

I want the information to be written to the History table first, then the "Auto-generated" ID in History for the respective matters should be passed as a Foreign key to the Diary table and inserted into a column (DY_H_ID).  At the moment, that column is not being populated with data as it was only added later.

Please see my code below:

```
        declare @U_ID varchar(50) 
        declare @Add_U_ID varchar(50)
        declare @Subject varchar(50)
        Declare @iPriority int
        declare @data xml
        declare @UN varchar(500)
        declare @Date varchar(50)
        declare @sDesc varchar(500)

        set @U_ID = 18185
        set @Add_U_ID = 18185 --'liihvcvbbbr43v55vx4wsk2x'
        set @Subject = 'Bulk'
        set @iPriority = 2
        set @data = '<Matters>
                        <string>G0000010</string>
                        <string>G0000011</string>
                    </Matters>'
        set @Date = '2013/08/23 17:00'
        set @sDesc = 'Diary item added for : 2013/08/23 17:00 <br/>User : Tommy de Longe <br/> Bulk PAM'

        select @UN = RTRIM(LTRIM(isNull(U_Name,'') + ' ' +  isNull(U_Surname,''))) from Users with(nolock) where id = @U_ID 
        ;with cte_Tmp ([MatterIDX], [MatterID]) as 
        ( 
        select null, ParamValues.M_ID.value('.','VARCHAR(50)') 
        from @data.nodes('/Matters/string') as ParamValues(M_ID) 
        ) 
        select Matter.M_IDX as M_IDX, [MatterID] as M_ID
        into #TBL_Matter 
        from cte_Tmp 
        inner join Matter with(nolock) on cte_Tmp.[MatterID] = Matter.ID 

        Insert Into Dairy(DY_IDX,DY_MatterNo,DY_UserID,DY_Date,DY_Subject,DY_Priority) 
        select #TBL_Matter.M_IDX, #TBL_Matter.M_ID, @U_ID, @Date, @Subject, @iPriority
        from #TBL_Matter

        Insert into History(H_IDX, H_MID,H_UserID,H_Description,H_HA_ID,H_HSA_ID) 
        select #TBL_Matter.M_IDX, #TBL_Matter.M_ID, @Add_U_ID, Replace(Replace(Replace(@sDesc,'@UN', @UN),'@Date', @Date),'@Subject', @Subject), 7,19 
        from #TBL_Matter

        drop table #TBL_Matter
```

I received this code to maintain and its breaking my head.  I know I need to switch the two inserts at the bottom of the query around, to insert into History table first, then get the corresponding auto-generated ID's (matter G0000010, matter G0000011) in this case then Insert those values into the Diary table.  Sometime the user can enter 20 values into the textbox, other times only 2, so it must be dynamic.

Any help with regards to this would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at [OUTPUT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @bummi.  I used OUTPUT to get the inserted ID's on the History table.  And then took the ID and identifier H_MID into a Table Variable called @MyTableVar.  Then on the INSERT of the Diary table, I joined to my Table Variable on the identifier.  Then I just add the Table Variable ID column to the insert list of the Diary table.  Works like a dream!  A big thanks to @bummi.  Below is my code:

```
        declare @U_ID varchar(50) 
        declare @Add_U_ID varchar(50)
        declare @Subject varchar(50)
        declare @iPriority int
        declare @data xml
        declare @UN varchar(500)
        declare @Date varchar(50)
        declare @sDesc varchar(500)

        declare @MyTableVar table
        (
            ID int NOT NULL,
            H_MID varchar(50)
        );

        set @U_ID = 18185
        set @Add_U_ID = 18185
        set @Subject = 'Bulk'
        set @iPriority = 2
        set @data = '<Matters>
                        <string>G0000010</string>
                        <string>G0000011</string>
                    </Matters>'
        set @Date = '2013/08/23 17:00'
        set @sDesc = 'Diary item added for : 2013/08/23 17:00 <br/>User : Tommy de Longe <br/> Bulk PAM'

        select @UN = RTRIM(LTRIM(isNull(U_Name,'') + ' ' +  isNull(U_Surname,''))) from Users with(nolock) where id = @U_ID;

        with cte_Tmp ([MatterIDX], [MatterID]) --Column names for Temporary table
        as 
        ( 
            select null, ParamValues.M_ID.value('.','VARCHAR(50)') 
            from @data.nodes('/Matters/string') as ParamValues(M_ID) 
        ) 
        select Matter.M_IDX as M_IDX, [MatterID] as M_ID
        into #TBL_Matter 
        from cte_Tmp 
        inner join Matter with(nolock) on cte_Tmp.[MatterID] = Matter.ID

        Insert into History(H_IDX, H_MID,H_UserID,H_Description,H_HA_ID,H_HSA_ID)
        OUTPUT inserted.ID, inserted.H_MID INTO @MyTableVar(ID, H_MID)
        select #TBL_Matter.M_IDX, #TBL_Matter.M_ID, @Add_U_ID, Replace(Replace(Replace(@sDesc,'@UN', @UN),'@Date', @Date),'@Subject', @Subject), 7,19 
        from #TBL_Matter

        Insert Into Dairy(DY_IDX,DY_MatterNo,DY_UserID,DY_Date,DY_Subject,DY_Priority,DY_H_ID) 
        select #TBL_Matter.M_IDX, #TBL_Matter.M_ID, @U_ID, @Date, @Subject, @iPriority, mtv.ID
        from #TBL_Matter
        inner join @MyTableVar as mtv on #TBL_Matter.M_ID = mtv.H_MID

        drop table #TBL_Matter
```